# WHERE clause with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query to count the amount of devices in my database. I try to add a WHERE clause to only select the device and count with the name "iphone".

```
SELECT device, count( * ) AS count, sum( 100 ) / total AS percentage
FROM devices WHERE device='apple'
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT count( * ) AS total
FROM devices
)x
GROUP BY 1
```

I tried to construct different queries, but they all result in a mysql error. What is the correct position of the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` comes **after** `FROM` and before `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT device, count( * ) AS count, sum( 100 ) / total AS percentage
FROM devices 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT count( * ) AS total
FROM devices
)x
WHERE device='apple'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can rewrite this query as:

```
SELECT 'apple' as device, sum(device = 'apple') AS count,
       100 * sum(device = 'apple') / count(*) AS percentage
FROM devices ;
```

This removes the extra table scan for calculating the total and the `join` (which is really cheap because there is only one row in `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Where goes before group by and fater from and join:

```
SELECT device, count( * ) AS count, sum( 100 ) / total AS percentage
FROM devices 
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT count( * ) AS total
FROM devices
)x
WHERE device='apple'
GROUP BY 1
```